# Laravel Enable to Download Export Project Zip file to Browser

Tags: php, css, html, laravel

I am trying to download  Zip file to my download folder in Computer. But it always downloaded to the projects public folder. What can be the issue?
Here is my code:

```
public function Zip($source, $destination)
    {
        if (!extension_loaded('zip') || !file_exists($source)) {
            return false;
        }
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        if (!$zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
            return false;
        }
        $source = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($source));
        if (is_dir($source) === true) {
            $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $file);
                // Ignore "." and ".." folders
                if (in_array(substr($file, strrpos($file, '/') + 1), array('.', '..'))) {
                    continue;
                }

                $file = realpath($file);

                if (is_dir($file) === true) {
                    //$zip->addEmptyDir($file);
                } elseif (is_file($file) === true) {
                    $nfile = explode('project_files', $file);
                    $zip->addFromString($nfile[1], file_get_contents($file));
                }
            }
        } elseif (is_file($source) === true) {
            $zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
        }

        return $zip->close();
    }
```